# High latency when transmitting with HackRF One from GNU Radio

Tags: lag, gnuradio, software-defined-radio

So I reverse-engineered an RC toy wireless protocol, and written a flow graph in GNU Radio Companion for reproducing the toy's commands.

The sink block is osmocom sink, and transmitting device is HackRF One.

The problem I encountered is severe lag between pressing button and toy reacting, which is about 1-2 seconds.

Quickly pressing, for example, "forward" button twice will result in toy jerking forward twice in quick succession as well, about a second after pressing. So it's not like the flow graph itself is slow. The CPU usage is also fairly low. This looks like some buffering issue.

I'm pretty sure that the flow graph itself reacts to button presses instantly, as debugging prints appear the same time as button is pressed/depressed, and square waves appear in the GUI scope sink instantly, as well.

I tried to lower number of HackRF buffers to one (by settings device arguments to `hackrf,buffers=1`), but it didn't help.

I set "Max Number of Outputs" to 10 for flow graph as well, and it also didn't make a difference (I tried some other values, too). Given that signal appears in the GUI scope much sooner than after 1 second, it shouldn't have worked anyway.

How can I reduce the latency then?

[image: GNU Radio Companion flow graph]

**EDIT**: I followed @Manos's suggestion and tried adjusting sample rate.

Adding a rational resampler block with interpolation of 8 (and adjusting sink sample rate accordingly) AND setting `hackrf,buffers=1` makes latency almost non-existent.

However, reducing output sample rate of my custom block to 500k and having 16x interpolation still causes noticeable lag, maybe 400-500ms (still not as dramatic as when it's 1M at both source and sink). I'm not sure how to fix it. Unfortunately, running my custom block at 1M consumes 100% CPU and causes occasional underflows.

Comment: If you double the sampling rate does the exhibited latency drops? I have experienced some great delays with the HackRF at low sampling rates but not at the order of seconds.

Comment: @Manos: thanks, I've tried your suggestions and they've improved the situation a bit. I've updated my question.

Comment: 1M should not be a problem in most cases for new CPUs. Perhaps you forgot the maximum number of output items in a small value? Also I am curious if something goes wrong with the scheduler. Can you provide more info about your block? Is it a sync block or a general one? Does always produces samples, or only when the button is pressed?

Comment: @Manos: it is a sync block, and it is written in pure Python (if I rewrote it in C, 1M certainly wouldn't be a problem). It always produces samples ("low" carrier signal). Once button is pressed, it immediately starts producing modulated bits. Here is the source: https://gist.github.com/WGH-/4c0a18b3bfff9dc97c4602f62ace028d